# what is wrong in my mysql 5.7 syntax?

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-web-services

```
CREATE TABLE tt_inv_refresh (
id int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
cust_id int,
res_type enum,
refresh_dtls JSON,
FOREIGN KEY (cust_id));
```

**Giving ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '
refresh_dtls JSON,
FOREIGN KEY (cust_id))' at line 4**

another table is created with **cust_id** as primary key

Comment: You haven't specified the values for your enum type.

Comment: Ok i have 3 enum pricing,elb,cf ..first time trying mysql..thanks for your ans..

Comment: The FK must reference a table.

Comment: `CREATE TABLE tt_inv_refresh (
id int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
cust_id int,
res_type enum('pricing','elb','cf'),
refresh_dtls JSON,
FOREIGN KEY (cust_id) REFERENCES tt_accounts(cust_id)
);`   working

Answer (score 2):

You have to name the foreign key constraint

```
FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) <- constraint named as parent_id
    REFERENCES parent(id) <- references primary key in other table
```